# how to pass ref variable to a SQL stored Procedure using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

i have that code using LINQ to call a stored procedure to save some data into database then return two variables from the stored procedure.

[ASP.NET code]

```
dbDataContext dbo = new dbDataContext();
dbo.AddNewDoctor(doctorName, email, password, ref DocId, ref result);
```

[SQL]

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewDoctor]
    @doctorname nvarchar(100),
    @email nvarchar(100),
    @password nvarchar(MAX),
    @docId int out,
    @Result int out

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @idCounter int
    select @idCounter = count(*) from dbo.doctors
    if EXISTS (select * from dbo.doctors where e_mail = @email) 
    begin
        SET @Result = -1
        set @docId= 0 
    end
    else
    begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[doctors]
           ([doctor_id]
           ,[doctorname]
           ,[e_mail]
           ,[password]           
     VALUES
           ((@idCounter +1)
           ,@docotorname
           ,@email
           ,@password
           )
            SET @Result = 1
            set @docId= (@idCounter + 1) 
    end 
END
```

this code work very well what i want to do now to use ADO instead of LINQ, the problem with me is that i can't pass the ref variable as in LINQ so how can i do it using ADO

Comment: NEVER use some thing like **set @docId= (@idCounter + 1)** in your code, beacuse it makes your program not multiuser-able.

Comment: thank u BendEg for advice but could u illustrate more as i didn't understand why

Comment: I would make your ID-Column to an Identity-Column and later get the new Identity with **@@IDENTITY** Because stored procedures can be executed at the same time, and than the system tries to set the same ID to both doctors. http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174639.aspx

Comment: @BendEg could u show it with a small example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this. Use  [ParameterDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx)

```
 SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter(paramName, dbType);
 output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 command.Parameters.Add(output);
```

In your case you've to use `SqlDbType.Int`. Use Value property to read return value.

```
SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter(paramName, SqlDbType.Int);
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(output);

int Result = (int) output.Value; or int? Result = (int?) output.Value;
```

Comment: @BendEg What I unsderstand is, It works with Linq but he now needs help with ADO

Comment: @BendEg he said he wants to do it in ADO.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i have tried that code and it give that exception
String[3]:the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: ' 
int? result = null;
int? DocId = null;
SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@docId", DocId) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
cmd.Parameters.Add(output);
SqlParameter output2 = new SqlParameter("@Result", result) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
 cmd.Parameters.Add(output2);'
'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();'

Comment: @SriramSakthivel looks we are very close now :)
it executes now without any problem but now i don't have the two return values i mean "Result and DocId"
as the code will be like that 
'SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };'

Comment: how can i hold my two return values from the stored procedure ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i'm really appreciate ur help, thank u very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand();
        mycommand.Connection = con;
        mycommand.CommandText = "dbo.AddNewDoctor";
        mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(doctorName);
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(email);
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(password);
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(ref DocId);
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(ref result);


        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Hope this helps thanks.

Comment: `AddWithValue` with multiple parameters at ones!! and with `ref`

Comment: you need to set `ParameterDirection`